# Error while using CassandraUnit: Dataset not found

Tags: java, unit-testing, cassandra

I'm trying to unit test Cassandra with CassandraUnit java library. Following the option 2 (exact code) from https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit/wiki/How-to-use-it-in-your-code#load-data-from-a-data-set which is supposed to load data from extendedDataSet.xml. It gives me this error.

```
org.cassandraunit.dataset.ParseException: Dataset not found

at org.cassandraunit.dataset.xml.AbstractXmlDataSet.<init>(AbstractXmlDataSet.java:39)
at org.cassandraunit.dataset.xml.ClassPathXmlDataSet.<init>(ClassPathXmlDataSet.java:10)
at com.visa.util.recordstore.cassandra.AutomaticallyStartAndLoadExtendedDataSetTest.getDataSet(AutomaticallyStartAndLoadExtendedDataSetTest.java:17)
at org.cassandraunit.AbstractCassandraUnit4TestCase.<init>(AbstractCassandraUnit4TestCase.java:19)
at com.visa.util.recordstore.cassandra.AutomaticallyStartAndLoadExtendedDataSetTest.<init>(AutomaticallyStartAndLoadExtendedDataSetTest.java:13)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:209)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:258)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:255)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Using cassandra-unit-3.0.0.1.jar, cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0.jar if that matters.

I have placed extendedDataSet.xml in the classpath. Any suggestion to fix this exception?

update:
the code:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.notNullValue;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.cassandraunit.dataset.IDataSet;
import org.cassandraunit.dataset.xml.ClassPathXmlDataSet;
import org.junit.Test;

public class AutomaticallyStartAndLoadExtendedDataSetTest extends       AbstractCassandraUnit4TestCase {

@Override
public IDataSet getDataSet() {
        return new ClassPathXmlDataSet("extendedDataSet.xml");
}

@Test
public void shouldHaveLoadAnExtendDataSet() throws Exception {
    //here, a Cassandra server is started and your data from extendedDataSet.xml has been loaded
    // you can query or do what you want
    assertThat(getKeyspace(), notNullValue());
    assertThat(getKeyspace().getKeyspaceName(), is("otherKeyspaceName"));
}

}
```

Comment: Can you copy the source code here ?

Comment: @doanduyhai updated the code

Comment: "I have placed extendedDataSet.xml in the classpath" --> Where exactly ? **/src/main/resources** ? **/src/test/resources** ?

Comment: @doanduyhai under /src/test/resources

Comment: were you able to solve your issue? I am also getting same error and I am using Option 3. Please post your answer if you were able to solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: @user1653027 no, unfortunately  I couldn't :(

Comment: Same issue here, but only on windows machines.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this issue and found that the configured CQL files had been moved to some other location. Fixing the configuration resolved issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

The main cause for this issue is the path to the cql file is wrong!